# How wait all thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have code, that create 5 threads. I need wait, until all threads finished their work, and after return value. How can I do this?

```
public static int num=-1;

public int GetValue()
{
    Thread t=null;
    for (int i = 0; i <=5; i++)
    {
        t = new Thread(() => PasswdThread(i));
        t.Start();  
    }

    //how wait all thread, and than return value?   
    return num;
}

public void PasswdThread(int i)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Random r=new Random();
    int n=r.Next(10);
    if (n==5)
    {
        num=r.Next(1000);
    }
}
```

Of course this is not a real code. The actual code is much more complicated, so I simplified it.

P.S. Look carefully. **I am not use Task, so I can't use method Wait() or WaitAll()**. Also I can't use Join(), because Join wait one thread. If they start wait thread, which already finished they work, the will wait infinity.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610.aspx

Comment: What do you expect `num` to be? This won't scale to real code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait for thread to finish with .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584062/how-to-wait-for-thread-to-finish-with-net)

Comment: @jon-maximys go to visual studio, *Tools> Options> Text Editor> All Languages> Tabs* and select **Insert spaces** option

Comment: you could go for thread.waitall().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a `ManualResetEvent` handle for each your thread, and then call `WaitHandle.WaitAll(handles)` in your main thread.

`static WaitHandle[] handles = new WaitHandle[5];`

`

```
public void PasswdThread(int i)
{
handles[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);

 Thread.Sleep(1000);
 Random r=new Random();
 int n=r.Next(10);
 if (n==5)
 {
     num=r.Next(1000);
 }
 handles[i].Set();
}
```

Get more information on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6.aspx

Comment: Rather than having n MRE's you could just have one semaphore initialized with a value of N; it would be simpler.  Although just using `Thread.Join` or `Thread.WaitAll` would likely be simpler still.

Answer (score 3):

Make an array of thread like below and call WaitAll function

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
Thread thread = null;
 for (int i = 0; i <=5; i++)
 {
     t = new Thread(() => PasswdThread(i));
     t.Start();
     threads.add(t);
 }
Thread.WaitAll(thread);
 //how wait all thread, and than return value?  
 return num;
```

Comment: Sorry @jon Maximys this function is not for threads, for threads you have to use thread pool try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: or you can use Task Library to implement the same

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Thread.WaitAll(thread_array)` or in other case you can also use `Thread.Sleep(100)`

In `Thread.sleep`, 100 is number of milliseconds. So in this case thread would sleep for 100 milliseconds.

And in `Thread.WaitAll` - `thread_Array` is array of threads that you wanna wait.

Comment: Real software doesn't `Sleep()`. It's certainly no replacement for Join/Wait.

Answer (score 0):

As this question is effectively a duplicate, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2569478/1185053), (code copied below, all credit to Reed Copsey.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int numThreads = 10;
        ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        int toProcess = numThreads;

        // Start workers.
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
        {
            new Thread(delegate()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                // If we're the last thread, signal
                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref toProcess) == 0)
                    resetEvent.Set();
            }).Start();
        }

        // Wait for workers.
        resetEvent.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
    }
}
```

---

### Aside

Also note that your `PasswdThread` code will not produce random numbers. The `Random` object should be declared statically, outside of your method, to produce random numbers.

Additionally you never use the `int i` parameter of that method.

Answer (score 0):

I would use TPL for this, imo it's the most up to date technique for handling this sort of synchronization.  Given the real life code is probably more complex, I'll rework the example slightly:

```
public int GetValue()
{
    List<Task<int>> tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
    for (int i = 0; i <=5; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(PasswdThread(i));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    // You can now query all the tasks:
    foreach (int result in tasks.Select(t => t.Result))
    { 
        if (result == 100) // Do something to pick the desired result...
        {
            return result;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

public Task<int> PasswdThread(int i)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Random r=new Random();
        int n=r.Next(10);
        if (n==5)
        {
            return r.Next(1000);
        }
        return 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: No! I can't use Task because it's a lot of problem with write file from thread.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Thread t=null;
List<Thread> lst = new List<Thread();
    for (int i = 0; i <=5; i++)
    {
         t = new Thread(() => PasswdThread(i));
         lst.Add(t);
         t.Start();  
    }

    //how wait all thread, and than return value?   
foreach(var item in lst)
{
    while(item.IsAlive)
    {
         Thread.Sleep(5);
    }
}
    return num;
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using a busywait; there are tools given to you to avoid needlessly consuming so many additional resources doing this.