# How sure all threads inside foreach completed, before running codes outside of foreach

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.5

here is my codes :

```
foreach (string s in ls)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        thread_inside(s, k);
    });
    thread.Start();
}

timer_between_freuqently_1.Enabled = true;
```

how can i sure all thread_inside() methods completed before running the codes outside of foreach?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528907/spawn-multiple-threads-for-work-then-wait-until-all-finished

Comment: I prefer [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2228508/1319106)

Comment: Use tasks. Append all created tasks to a List. and then use : Task.WhenAll(myTaskList.ToArray()); it will wait all task